# AngularJS REST call to another server

Tags: angularjs, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I'm using the [Yeoman generator for AngularJS](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular#readme) and I would like to interact with a REST server (who uses Spring Boot).

In my computer:

- AngularJS app starts with Grunt on http://localhost:9000/
- Spring Boot app is on http://localhost:8080/

In my AngularJS app I have a service like that :

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .factory('User', ['$resource',
    function($resource){
      return $resource('http://localhost:8080/poc/hello', {}, {
        query: {method:'GET'}
      });
  }]);
```

And here is the controller :

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('RegisterCtrl', ['$scope', 'User', function($scope, User) {
      $scope.hello = User.query();
}]);
```

In my Java app :

```
@RestController("poc")
public class PocController {

    @RequestMapping("hello")
    public String getHello() {
        return "Hello World !";
    }
}
```

But when I want to do the call, I'm being blocked by "CORS"...

What is the best way to do what I want to do ? Not only for GET request, but POST, etc...

Is it possible to "configure" the REST server URL (http://localhost:8080/) once and make all AngularJS call (like `/poc/hello`) redirected to http://localhost:8080/poc/hello ? If yes, how ?

Comment: Read this [Guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set headers in your rest server, following is some data I set on my node server but the details should help:

```
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:9000'
'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE'
'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'X-Requested-With,content-type'
'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': false
```